# How can I see which processes locked a file?

Tags: linux, process, files

How do you find out which processes have a lock on a given file, in Linux?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to `lslk`, you could also try `lsof`.

Answer (score 4):

Try [fuser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuser_%28Unix%29)

In the example below, I have run fuser against a jar file and it has shown me the pids for the processes using the jar.

```
$ fuser app.jar

app.jar:    15529m   26293m   23017m
```

Answer (score 1):

You try [lslk](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lslk)?

Comment: lslk is old stuff; for example, it does not appear anymore in newer releases of RHEL than 3.

Comment: Yeah, lsof was what I was thinking of. But it was already on my Debian 
Etch box, so go figure.